# How to assign individual to-do task to each member in group

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I am using List workflow on Document library using Sharepoint designer Foundation 2013(2010 Workflow Platform).

I want to assign task individual task to each member from Sharepoint group. Is it possible? If yes then how. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

When setting up the Group you need to ensure the setting 'group membership is viewable' by 'Everyone' (not just the members) to ensure the WF can read the group members.

Once done you can then assign a WF task to a Group name opposed to an individual

Comment: I Created group eg: DocReviewer, added 3 members. Now When I set Assign to-do item to sharepoint group(DocReviewer) its add single task item for all group members and when any one of them click 'Complete Task' workflow gets completed. I want to do task would be individual for each group member so that individual can complete his own task item until WF should pause